# How do I access the index of a selected item in list using React and Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to pass the index of the menu item selected onChange but don't know how to access it.

```
     const handleListChange = (e) => {
       console.log('Item Index: ', e.target.key);
     }


      <TextField
        select
        label="Select item"
        value={show}
        onFocus={getListArray}
        onChange={e => handleListChange(e)}
      >
        {listArray.map((value, index) =>
          <MenuItem
            key={index}
            value={value.title}
          >
            {value.title}
          </MenuItem>
        )}
      </TextField>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to get an array of titles and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the index of the selected item.

And here it is with ES6 and arrow syntax, which is even simpler:

```
const handleListChange = (e) => {
  const index = listArray.map(item => item.title).indexOf(e.target.value);
  console.log(index);
}
```